# Finding the prime factors of a positive number

Tags: beginner, c, primes, homework, factors

I have an assignment to write on the standard output the prime factors of a positive number displayed in ascending order and separated by '*'. My code works, but I need help reviewing it before I submit my work. Allowed functions: `write, printf, atoi`.

```
void    find_factors(int n)
{
    int i;
    int separated;

    i = 3;
    separated = 0;
    if (n <= 1)
        return ;
    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (separated)
            printf("*");
       printf("%d", 2);
       separated = 1;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    while (i <= n)
    {
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            if (separated)
                printf("*");
            printf("%d", i);
            separated = 1;
            n = n / i;
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    if (n > 2)
    {
      if (separated)
            printf("*");
      printf("%d", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to quite work.  `find_factors(72);` prints `2*2*2**3*3`.  Please test more, fix the bug and then update the question.

Comment: @Edward I have updated the question and fixed the bug. I have also removed `my_sqrt, my_printnbr` and `my_putchar` functions.

Answer (score 4):

1) The reasons for 2 loops `while (n % 2 == 0)` and `while (i <= n)` is to optimize division by 2 and allow the next prime candidate to be found with `+= 2`.

As printing is a sink-hole of time, these small savings could be ignored and code changed to one loop.

```
int i = 2;
while (i <= n) {
   while(n % i == 0) {
      ...
      printf("%d", i);
      separated = 1;
      n = n / i;
   }
   i += i==2 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

2) Negative numbers are a problem and not well supported here, nor do they need to be.  Recommend `unsigned` than `int`.

3) As an alternative to a flag and repeated test code for the `"*"`, perhaps

```
char *separator = "";
...
while (...) {
   printf("%s%d", separator, 2);
   separator = "*";
   ...
}
```

4) Code fails for the following.  OP did say "prime factors of a positive number", so 0 and negative numbers are excusable to some degree.

```
  find_factors(INT_MAX);  // infinite loop
  find_factors(1);        // no output
  find_factors(0);        // infinite loop
  find_factors(negative)  // no output
```

5) Initialize at the same time as declaration.

```
// int i;
// int separated;
// i = 3;
// separated = 0;
int i = 3;
int separated = 0;
```

6) Consider `bool` for boolean variables

```
#include <stdbool.h>
// int separated = 0;
bool separated = false;
```

7) Wavy formatting

```
    if (separated)
        printf("*");
   printf("%d", 2);
   separated = 1;
    n = n / 2;
```

8) Careful passing a string to `printf()` as a format string as it *might* someday contain `%`.

```
// printf("*");
fputs("*", stdout);
// or 
fputc('*', stdout);
//
putchar('*');

// OP did say  "write, printf, atoi.", so could use the following, which is a bit pedantic.
printf("%s", "*");
```

9) Efficiency.  For large values of `n`, code does `n/2` loops.  Better to terminate at about the `sqrt(n)`.  At `n % i` time, also calculate `qu = n / i`.  This can often be had for free, depending on the processor.  Once `i>qu`, code is done.